# Call a post inside an include ( i think )

Tags: php

I'm trying to learn PHP, and to do so im trying to create a code to register new products, i've made an loggin access where the person to do so needs to be connected, so inside of the cpanel I did differents sections, like add client, add product...

So i did an index in the _cpanel folde where i have my main html and to not repeat the same html i put an include inside this index so i can call others php files inside.

I dont know if its correctly to do like this BUT, as i said Im new at programming..

But everything works pretty good, until i need to call my post in my url..

like.. to add a new product i need to go to :

**localhost** -> connect... to go to **localhost/_cpanel**

if i click in add a new produt, i go to **localhost/_cpanel/?page=folder/addnewproduct.php**

and inside this php file i put a form with an action="?**go=addnewproduct**"

so, i did everything to put all the info in my db, but when i submit it goes to

**localhost/_cpanel/?go=addnewproduct** and nothing happens..

i tried to change the action like action="folder/?page=addnewproduct.php&?go=addnewproduct" but it doesnt work either.

BUT i made it works changing to action"folder/addnewproduct.php?go=newproduct

but to do so i need to go to "addnewproduct.php", and this page only is an included page inside my index..

i could call back to the index page after adding a new product, so that it doesnt show this page only, but when posting it loads fast to the page and after than it go back to my _cpanel.

i tried to find solutions but, didnt find... i think its just a problem with the way i put it in my action, maybe theres a way to do it and i dont know it yet.

Comment: It would be even better if you show us the pertinent codes for your issues...

Comment: Dont add textual info.. Put the code with actual erros you are facing

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I get what you're wanting exactly, but here you go:

If you're trying to redirect the request, you may just use the `header` function as follows:

```
header('Location: target/url.php');
```

If you want to make a external post request with php, you may use `curl`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code):

[PHP + curl, HTTP POST sample code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code)